# GCP の VPC ネットワークピアリング間で MySQL 接続が ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform

Google Cloud Platform にて2つの VPC 間を MySQL (3306) でローカル接続しようとしていますが、疎通できずに困っています。

VPCネットワーク A (10.1.0.0/24) と B (10.2.0.0/24) を新規で作成し、VPC ネットワークピアリングは双方向で有効になった状態にあります。

VPCA (10.1.0.2) から VPCB (10.2.0.2) に対して以下の通り接続を試しても、エラーになってしまいます。

```sh
$ mysql -u root -p -h 10.2.0.2 –port=3306

ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '10.2.0.2:3306' (110)
```

GCP ファイアウォールもそれぞれ 3306 を許可してあります。
何か設定が足りないのでしょうか？よろしくお願いいたします。